# loadStripe keeps giving me {type: "invalid_request_error", message: "Invalid API Key provided: undefined"} error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

```
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';

const apiKey = `${process.env.REACT_STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY}`;
const stripePromise = loadStripe(apiKey);
```

After the promise is fulfilled, `_apiKey` in the `stripePromise` object is undefined.

Have been stuck on this error for days. Anyone care to help.

Thanks and much appreciated

Comment: did you try to console log the key to see if it's defined? seems like it's undefined, can you please show how you setup .env, without showing your private key?

Comment: How is the environment variable stored? As an actual environment variable or in a `.env` file? Is the environment variable set when you start the application? You may want to `console.log` it, as David mentioned.

Comment: I just tried console logging the key now and to my surprise its undefined. How's this possible? I have other keys setup in my app and console logging them gives me the correct response. What could be the issue?  In my .env file i wrote(REACT_STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY = pk_test_..... )

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured this out guys. Apparently, .env variables in react had to be prefixed with REACT_APP_ then variable name.

Changing my variable name from REACT_STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY to REACT_APP_STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY fixed the bug. Thank you you for the insight much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`process.env.REACT_STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY` is most likely empty.  It's also unlikely to be available client-side, so likely needs to be rendered as part of the build process.

Comment: Console logging apikey actually returns undefined. I dont know how that is because am writing only front end code as am using commercejs

Answer (score 0):

Side note because I was facing the same issue even though I had my env variable named correctly...
I was trying to give the variable to the loadStripe function like:

`` loadStripe(`${process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY}`); ``

It came back undefined so the solution for me was to put it into a local variable outside of the component definition first like written above and give that to the function:

```
const apiKey = `${process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY}`;
```

Than I passed this key to the function later:

```
const stripe = await loadStripe(apiKey);
```

Hope it will be useful for someone too.